# Common ground and voltages, Part 2

Tags: voltage, ground

To further my understanding of what happens when 2 circuits have a common ground could someone please explain what happens when the following 2 circuits (charged capacitor, high resistance load) :

[image: no common ground]

share a common ground

[image: common ground]

What happens to the 2 voltages and capacitor plate potentials ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Wouter van Ooijen said, but also the bottom halves of the two circuits are guaranteed to be at the same potential. You seem to be wondering why anyone would ever care about this.

To demonstrate why this important, go find a stereo or something with an audio plug coming out of it like you'd plug into an iPod or such. Turn up the volume just a bit, and touch just the tip of the connector. Hear that buzz? It's because your body is picking up all sorts of electrical fields from the electronics in your house and nature. These are at different potentials from the stereo, and it amplifies them as sound and you can hear it.

Now, touch *all* the parts on the plug. Squeeze so you get a good connection. The buzz is gone! Why? Because now you have a common ground. All those fields are still there, but now your body and the stereo are at the same potential, so there's no difference between you and the radio, so you don't hear anything. (Or not as much, anyway. The connection isn't infinitely conductive, so you will still hear something, if you turn the volume up more.)

So, your stereo amplifies the voltage *difference* between its idea of "ground" and the left and right channels on the connector. But if something (your body, an iPod, whatever) isn't connected to the stereo's ground, then the stereo will be amplifying the voltage output by the iPod and also the difference in ground between the iPod and the stereo, which is likely some crazy random noise and 60/50 Hz hum from powerlines. Giving the two a common ground reduces this difference to nearly zero, so that the two circuits can have a common reference, so they can agree what "4V" means.

Comment: Initially the bottom halves are not at the same potential and then when they are connected they are at the same potential. So something has changed. So what are the new plate charges and capacitor voltages ?

Comment: @FunkyOordvork: there are only relative voltages, not absolute ones. The voltage difference between the leads of each capacitor will be unchanged. In your second schematic, I can also tell you that the voltage difference between the bottom leads of either capacitor is 0V, but in the first all I can't know. One would say they are "floating" relative to each other. They could be the same, or they could be 100V apart. We don't know, and the circuit doesn't care.

Answer (score 2):

For the (somewhat theoretical) case you show nothing different from the not-connected case will happen, in fact nothing CAN happen because there is no (additional) closed current path.

Comment: So will there be no movement of charge between the 2 lower capacitor plates when they are connected ? Does the fact that they have different charges (initially) not create a voltage between the lower plates ?

Comment: @FunkyOordvork it can't because there's nowhere it could flow. I think you should give [Bill Beaty's article](http://amasci.com/emotor/cap1.html) a read.

Comment: Okay, I just imagined what would happen if I connected 2 'water spheres' where one had its rubber plate bent twice as much as the other. Thanks Phil / Bill !

Comment: Funky: unconnected capacitors have not water balloon equivalent. The capacitor equivalent of your water balloon picture would have (for instance) one side of each capacitor grounded in the first place.

Comment: Wouter: My first diagram corresponds to 2 unconnected "water spheres" where one has its rubber plate bent twice as much as the other (double the voltage). You can complete the circuit with a very thin hose (high resistance load) in both cases.

Comment: The second diagram corresponds to the same setup but with the spheres connected (high pressure side to high pressure). The water still can't move as there is no circuit (except for the hose and it is very thin). It is obvious with water. Not sure why I had such a problem with electric charge :)

Comment: Sorry Funky, you are wrong. As I said, you simply can't create a water balloon analog of your first circuit. Your unconnected water balloons are in the same world, that alone suffices to make their capacitor analog have a common ground. Water is not a perfect analog for all electrical circuits.

Comment: Enough electrons will flow to to equalize the potential of both sides.  In most cases, not enough to do any real work, but a non-zero quantity (unless the potentials were equal to start with).

Comment: @Funky: the best analog to your two water balloons is two (unequally) charged bodies. When you connect them current will indeed flow. But if you want to represent two charged bodies they eeach form a capacitor with th earth as other plate, so again they are connected at one side from the start.

Comment: @supercat : that's what I thought at the start. I knew it wasn't a circuit but I thought the electron equalisation might change the capacitor voltages. But then I changed my mind due to water analogy. Now I'm beginning to doubt myself again !

Comment: @Wouter : the unconnected water spheres haves different pressures on each side (due to differently stretched rubber plates). Is that not the equivalent of the different plate charges in my first diagram ?

Comment: No. Your balloons share a common pressure reference point, because pressure is an absolute value. Voltage is not an absolute value, it is always relative. You can't charge something to 100V without stating *in reference to which 0V ground*.

Comment: @Wouter : surely charge per square meter (or is it cubic meter ?) is an absolute value. I have tried to be careful to talk about charge / potential rather than voltage (except when talking about the volatges across the capacitor plates)

Comment: @FunkyOordvork: Electron equalization will definitely change the capacitor voltages.  In most cases, however, if there was no connection between the two sides of the circuit, such equalization won't "do" anything.  Note that in most damaging electrostatic discharge events, there is a hidden capacitive connection between the things being touched, which means the number of electrons that get pushed through the break-over point var exceeds the number of electrons by which the objects as a whole were unbalanced.

Comment: @supercat : In your answer below you say that a very small amount of electrons flow from one capacitor plate to the other (from -2qC plate to -qC plate I hope). So does that mean that the 2V drops slightly and the 1V increases slightly ? Does the same thing happen when you common ground 2 power supplies i.e. the voltage of both changes slightly but not enough to worry about ?

Comment: @FunkyOordvork: If, before the two capacitors were connected, plate -2qC was 0.5 volts below plate -qC, then a few electrons would flow from the latter to the former until the plates were at the same potential.  The potential at 2qC would be shifted upward by essentially the same amount as that of -2qC, and the potential at QC would be shifted down by essentially the same amount as -qC, such that the differences between 2qC and -2qC, or qC and -qC, would be essentially unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Enough electrons will flow between newly-connected plates to bring them to the same potential.  From a practical perspective, though, unless something else not shown on the schematic behaves as a significant capacitance connection between the two halves of the circuit, however, the number of electrons that will have to flow to equalize the potentials will be really, really small.  Really, really, really, really small.

Think of the voltage at any given point as relating to its willingness to accept or donate electrons; if two points have the same voltage, electrons will have no particular desire to favor one direction or the other.  If one point has a higher voltage, electrons will prefer moving in that direction to moving in the reverse.  The higher the difference in voltages, the greater the preference.

If an electron arrives on either one of a capacitor's plate, it will make every part of the capacitor be much less accepting of electrons (i.e. decrease its voltage).  Conversely, every time an electron leaves one of the plates, it will make every part be much more accepting of electrons (increase the voltage).  Note that if many more capacitors enter an electron than leave, both plates will have a very large negative voltage, such that electrons will jump at the opportunity to leave.

What is significant about a capacitor is that when an electron enters one plate, it causes that opposite plate's voltage to decrease slightly less than that of the plate receiving the electron.  Consequently, if the balance of electrons entering one plate exceeds that of the other, the plate which receives excess electrons will start to have a more negative voltage than the plate which doesn't, but the amount of imbalance between the two plates that is required to achieve that *vastly* exceeds the imbalance of electrons entering or leaving the device as a whole which would be required to change both plates' voltage by that amount.

Thus, unless there is some effective capacitance or other connection between the left and right sides, the number of electrons that might have to flow between the two sides to balance out their voltages would be vanishingly insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

Next to nothing happens because the connection you have made does not create a circuit, and so current will not flow through it, except to equalize any differences caused by static electricity buildup.   Static electricity buildup will appear on both plates of the capacitor: it's an excess or deficiency of electrons in the circuit as a whole. That exchange will not change the charges on the capacitors. Neither capacitor can discharge via the connection to the opposite circuit because that connection isn't a complete circuit.

What the connection means is that the two circuits now share a common reference voltage. Thus now it is meaningful to answer questions like "what is the potential difference between the top of the left resistor and the top of the right resistor".

If you add one more connection bridging the two, then you have a complete circuit. Some current can then flow through one connection and, of course, an opposite and equal current will return through the other.

A "common ground" serves this purpose: to return the currents exchanged by the other connections.  It is not a true ground in the earth sense; only a common return that is called "ground" out of hubris.

Which connection is "ground" is just a convention (but of course there are design reasons for choosing a particular connection, rather than choosing arbitrarily!). We assert that the voltage on that network is 0V, and then other voltages are referenced to that.